# AnnotationFormatError when adding Config annotation during start of Robolectric test

Tags: android, robolectric

I try to write a basic robolectric test.

When I start a test I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: 
Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class 
org.robolectric.annotation.Config.application()
```

When I remove `@Config` annotation:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/app/Application
at org.robolectric.annotation.Config$Builder.<init>(Config.java:376)
```

Fragment of my test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Mock
    private MyType myTypeMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDoFoo() {
```

In my build.gradle:

```
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3.2'
```

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project. Also show us your build.config, specifically the dependencies for robolectric which you are using.

Comment: Added, using 3.3.2

Comment: I suggest you google the error message and look for suggestions from the Robotium repo on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this in Android Studio 3.4.2 and  compileSdkVersion 28, robolectric 4.3

My Test has this initial config:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1])
class MyTest {
}
```

And what did the trick was to add this next line to the gradle.properties:

```
android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources=true
```